# how macro works different with integers and char in my C-code

Tags: c, if-statement, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'am familiar with the conditional compilation with macros in "C" language but some piece of code makes me confused ,I can understand how CODE-1 works, nothing is assigned into X therefore Y is defined as 5 (else condition) and on print Y we will get 5 as a output.

but in the `CODE-2` which is quite similar to the `CODE-1` except the
`"#if X == A"` condition which gives the output as `3`,which i don't understand how it can produce output as `3` .Can anyone tells me how

```
 "#if X == 3"
```

and

```
"#if X == A"`
```

makes the difference in the output.

---

**CODE-1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if X == 3
#define Y 3
#else
#define Y 5
#endif

int main()
{
  printf("%d", Y);
  return 0;
}

//output : 5
```

---

**CODE-2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if X == A
#define Y 3
#else
#define Y 5
#endif

int main()
{
  printf("%d", Y);
  return 0;
}

//output : 3
```

> I expect the output of `CODE-2` to be `5`, but the actual output is `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tokens in macro conditionals that aren't further expandable to integers (aren't macros) get replaced by 0.

[6.10.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4):

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing
>   tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are
>   replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary
>   operator), just as in normal text. If the token defined is generated
>   as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary
>   operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro
>   replacement, the behavior is undefined. After all replacements due to
>   macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed,
>   **all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to
>   keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each
>   preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens
>   compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated
>   according to the rules of 6.6.

Since neither `X` nor why `Y` is defined in your second snippet, it becomes equivalent to:

```
#if 0 == 0
#define Y 3
#else
#define Y 5
#endif
```

which naturally resolves to the first branch.